# SQL Ranking Function. Filter based on ranking result without a wrapper SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I have:

```
1, 'a'
2, 'a'
3, 'b'
4, 'b'
```

And I want to select the rows of each 'letter' which the highest 'id' to produce:

```
2, 'a'
4, 'b'
```

I can do it like below.

**But is it possible to do this without having to wrap the extra SELECT around the whole thing?**

```
declare @t table (id int, txt varchar)

insert into @t (id, txt)
select 1, 'a' union
select 2, 'a' union
select 3, 'b' union
select 4, 'b'

select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by txt order by id desc) as row_num
    from @t
) z
where row_num = 1
```

Comment: Why would not want to use subquery? how about use `CTE`?

Comment: What problem does the extra select cause? Too much typing?

Comment: I'm sure I've see it done... and it just adds to the complexity of complicated queries.

Comment: Sometimes "a little more complex" = "a little more resilient", but either answer below gives the simpler code.

Comment: The example was just the most simple example I could give. When dealing with state machines you may need for example to select the second time something enters into a specific state. You can't do that with a MAX.

Comment: And there's the "little more resilient" thing. Using the `ROW_NUMBER` gives you flexibility that simpler code doesn't. I'd stick with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, txt FROM @t GROUP BY txt;
```

This groups by the `txt` column and gets the maximum `id` for each of these.

Results:

```
id          txt
----------- ----
2           a
4           b
```